# Netty : How to change InterestOps on socket?

Tags: netty

How do you change the interestOps for a TCP socket w/ Netty.

I have a architecture I'm thinking about porting to Netty, and one feature of the existing framework is that while it's processing a message it removes the inbound socket's interest in OP_READ. Guaranteeing it won't be interrupted by another call to read until it's done w/ the current message. (which might be many calls to select() later).

It looks like there is a bunch of code to entirely rebuild the SelectKeys when a socket is added/removed. But I don't see anyplace the just changes the interestOps. But I'm new to Netty so I'm assuredly looking in the wrong place.

It's not really clear to me how to do this is Netty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `channel.config().setAutoRead(false)` which will remove the "read interest" and then once you want to read again you would use `channel.config().setAutoRead(true)`.